# Data structure to use in Sencha Touch similar to Vector in Blackberry

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am a beginner to sencha Touch, basically i am a blackberry developer. Currently we are migrating our application to support Sencha Touch 1.1. Now i  have some business solutions like i want to store the selected values in the local database. I mean i have multiple screens where, Once the user selects a value in each of the screen the data should save in the below following format.

**[{'key1': "value1", 'key2': "value2", 'key3': "value3" ,'key4': "value4", 'key5': "value5"}]**

**1. First, the values need to be saved in key value pairs**

**2. The keys should play the role of primary key, key shouldn't be duplicated.**

**3. Should be available till the application life cycle or application session, don't need to save the data permanently.**

I have come across the concepts like LocalStorageProxy, JsonStore and some others. I don't understand which one i can use for my specific requirements.

May be my question is bit more confusing. I have achieved the same using vector, in Blackberry Java so any data structure similar to this could help me. Need the basic operations like

1. Create
2. Add
3. Remove
4. Remove all
5. Fetch elements based on key

Please suggest me some samples or some code snapshots, which may  help me to achieve this.

**Edit: 1**

I have done the changes as per @Ilya139 's answer. Now I am able to add the data with key,

```
// this is my Object declared in App.js
NSDictionary: {},

// adding the data to object with key
MyApp.NSDictionary['PROD'] = 'SONY JUKE BOX';

//trying to retrieve the elements from vector 
var prod = MyApp.NSDictionary['PROD'];
```

**Nut not able to retrieve the elements using the above syntax.**

Comment: did you get some error? This is standard Javascript dictionary object.  Just try in firebug console, chrome console or jsfiddle you will see that is working. `var obj= {}; obj['s'] = 's'; obj['s'];` Also note that the `MyApp` should be the name of your sencha touch app, i.e. `var App = new Ext.Application({name: 'MyApp',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to save the data permanently then you can just have a global object with the properties you need. First define the object like this:

```
 new Ext.Application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    vectorYouNeed: {},
   launch: function () { ...
```

Then add the key-value pairs to the object like this

```
 MyApp.vectorYouNeed[key] = value;
```

And fetch them like this

```
 value = MyApp.vectorYouNeed[key];
```

Note that key is a string object i.e. `var key='key1';` and value can be any type of object.

To remove one value `MyApp.vectorYouNeed[key] = null;` And to remove all of them `MyApp.vectorYouNeed = {};`